# possible to be generic over types of a specific size?

Tags: rust

I have two types, `A` and `Storage`, where the role of `Storage` is to contain `A`s. Rather than hardcoding in `A`, I'd like to make `Storage` accept a generic parameter (makes the separation of concerns clearer, and I can swap in something simpler for testing), but the exact size of `A` is important. Therefore, is it possible to have something morally like

```
struct Storage<A: 8 bytes> { ... }
```

Comment: Would a global `const` with defined size for `A` not work here?

Comment: @MUFF. I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Something like what you presented is not possible, and probably never will. This however feels like a [XY question](https://xyproblem.info/). What exactly do you want to prevent?

Comment: You actually want the opposite of what your title asks, you want to specify the size and thus *not* be generic over the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in unstable Rust:

```
#![allow(incomplete_features)]
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

enum Assert<const CHECK: bool> {}

trait IsTrue {}

impl IsTrue for Assert<true> {}

struct Storage<A>
where
    Assert<{ core::mem::size_of::<A>() == 8 }>: IsTrue,
{
    _a: A,
}
    
fn main() {
    let _ok = Storage::<u64> { _a: 0, };
    // let _ko = Storage::<u16> { _a: 0, };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d78dda23e46673d19f26a0e975cc171b)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to ensure the user can only create 8-byte-long types, then you can use a const. This is what [bytemuck](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/1.14.0/src/bytemuck/must.rs.html#13) does.

```rs
pub struct Storage<A>(A);

impl<A> Storage<A> {
    const ASSERT_SIZE_EQUAL: () = assert!(std::mem::size_of::<A>() == 8);
    pub fn new(a: A) -> Self {
        let _ = Self::ASSERT_SIZE_EQUAL;
        Self(a)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _ = Storage::new([0u8; 8]);
    // Compile error
    // let _ = Storage::new([0u8; 9]);
}
```

Be careful using this for safety, since just because a type is 8 bytes long doesn't mean it can represent any pattern of 8 bytes, contains 8 initialized bytes, or has proper alignment. Size is not a guarantee of conversion safety.

Some alternatives:

- `impl<A: From<[u8; 8]> + Into<[u8; 8]>> Storage<A>`
- Use bytemuck to ensure types are convertible to/from bytes.